# While accessing localhost gives an error unable to read the security policy file for trust level 'wss_custom'

Tags: 2010, error, sharepoint-on-prem, iis, server

While accessing localhost gives an error unable to read the security policy file for trust level 'wss_custom'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like SharePoint is unable to read the wss_custom security policy. You have to check the Web.config files on all web front end make sure that the trust level is set properly.

i.e. something like this

```
<securityPolicy>
......
<trustLevel name="WSS_Custom" policyFile="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\config\wss_custom.config" />
</securityPolicy>
```

On this path, make sure you have correct wss_custom.config file and lastly it is properly registered.

Check the more detail here: http://techsolutions-at-desk.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-create-new-custom-trust-level.html

Comment: I could not access your link

Comment: what error you are getting? but did you check if your custom config file is in place and correct

Comment: I have 2 WFE servers and i dont see wss_custom.config

Comment: that is problem, if you setup custom policy then this file should be there. or revert it to back.

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to read the security policy file
>   for trust level 'WSS_Custom'.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.SetTrustLevel(TrustSection trustSection,
>   SecurityPolicySection securityPolicySection) +11467590
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags
>   hostingFlags) +11481518
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to read the security policy file
>   for trust level 'WSS_Custom'.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11432982
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4408276